# How to make a fade-out at the end of the sound in howlerjs?

Tags: javascript, web, audio, howler.js

In howler.js is possible to make fade.

`sound1.fade(1, 0, 2000);`

But this fade fires when sound1 starts playing.

How can I make fade-out in last 2 seconds of given sound in howler.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can think to do this is simply waiting for the appropriate time to fade:

```
sound1.on('play', function(){
  var fadeouttime = 2000;
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      sound1.fade(1, 0, fadeouttime);
    },
    (sound1.duration() - sound1.seek())*1000 - fadeouttime
  );
});
```

Something like that. The only thing you'd have to worry about is cancelling the timeout if the audio is paused, stopped, etc. I'm not aware of a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yea, I think this is only one possible solution. But on fade end there is also need for set volume to 1. If you play again this sound, there will be silence to the moment of fade.